# How to set value to second page textfield from Main page textfield

Tags: qt, qml, alias

I have textfields on main.qml and second.qml page. When I'm setting value to main.page textfield I want to set same value to second.page textfield.I use alias propery but not get expected output.

```
ApplicationWindow {
id: windowObject
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480

StackView {
    id: stack
    initialItem: view

    Component {
        id: view

        MouseArea {
            Text {
                text: stack.depth
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
            onClicked: stack.push(view)
        }
    }
}

TextField{
    id: setvalue
    text:"50" // set value from main page
}

Button{
    id: clickme
    text : "ClickMe"
    x: 100
    y:200
    onClicked: {
        console.debug("New Page")
        stack.pop(StackView.Immediate)
        stack.push (Qt.resolvedUrl("Secondpage.qml"))
    } }}
```

Secondpage.qml:

```
Item {
    id: name
    property alias value : getvalue.text
    TextField{
        id: getvalue
        text : "" // value from main page TextField
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use a `rootContext` property, see [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html), probably even a model. Please note that QML quite strongly guides you to model-views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I didn't find where you exactly using your second page. 
Let's suppose it should be on the main screen as well. Then your code should looks like some thing like that:

```
Window {
   id: windowObject
   visible: true
   width: 640
   height: 480

   TextField{
      id: setvalue
      text:"50" // set value from main page
   }

   Secondpage {
       id: _secondPageItem
       anchors.top: setvalue.bottom
       value: setvalue.text
   }
}
```

Secondpage.qml

```
Item { // Secondpage.qml
    id: name
    property alias value : getvalue.text
    width: getvalue.width // by default item has geometry (0, 0)
    height: getvalue.heigh

    TextField{
       id: getvalue
       text : "" // value from main page TextField
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using stackview to open new page, I edited code, using stackview how to set value to  second page's textfield?

Comment: here is the way to pass the parameters:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html#push-method

Comment: try the following:
stack.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("Secondpage.qml"), {"value": setvalue.text})